# Python, I want to convert a specific column type after importing a csv file

Tags: python, csv, types, casting

```
import numpy as np

data_arr = np.loadtxt("asset.csv", delimiter = ",", dtype = 'str')
data_arr
```

**Result:**

```
array([['G1', '1', '100', '5', '0'],

['G1', '1', '21', '538', '0'],

['G1', '1', '22', '6000', '0'],

...,

['G2', '8', '61', '241908', '8800'],

['G2', '8', '70', '57341', '16800'],

['G2', '9', '51', '1340', '0']], dtype='<U7')
```

But I want to convert `2,3,4,5` columns(The `'1', '100', '5', and '0'` fields in the first row) to `int` type

because I want to try

```
family_number = np.array([1,2,3,4,100])

capital = data_arr[data_arr[:,0]=="G1"]

for i, number in enumerate(family_number):

    family_numbers = capital[capital[:,1]>i] & capital[capital[:,1]<=number]

    print("\t" + len(family_numbers))
```

How can I convert type of columns? Please help!

Comment: use `dtype = 'int64'`. Any reason for giving `str` as dtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the proper types of columns:

```
np.loadtxt('asset.csv', delimiter=",", dtype='S20,int64,int64,int64,int64')
```

EDIT: list the maximum string length alongside. E.g. this should now work assuming your first column doesn't exceed 20 characters.

Comment: When I do that, 'str' field disappears! array([('', 1, 100,      5,     0), ('', 1,  21,    538,     0),
       ('', 1,  22,   6000,     0), ..., ('', 8,  61, 241908,  8800),
       ('', 8,  70,  57341, 16800), ('', 9,  51,   1340,     0)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4')])

Comment: I'm sorry for so many questions, but there is 2 problems.
first, it says
TypeError: data type "s20" not understood.
Second, when I type 'str,int,int,int,int' instead of what you recommend, it says
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: `s20` is not `S20`.

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the result and use `astype`:

```py
arr = np.array([['1', '2', '3'], ['3', '4', '5'], ['5', '6', '7']])
arr
# array([['1', '2', '3'],
#        ['3', '4', '5'],
#        ['5', '6', '7']], dtype='<U1')

arr[:,1:].astype(int)
# array([[2, 3],
#        [4, 5],
#        [6, 7]])
```

I mean, the other answers and comments (@Amadan's, for example) seem correct in that you could import them with different data types in the first place. But, if you're stuck after the fact, code like the above should work.

Comment: It seems to have been converted, but after that, there is another problem like this 
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
df[col_bame]=df[can l_name].astype(int)
```